# Why is Spring telling me the controller is an unknown entity upon saving a user?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, controller, entity

After a few hours of running against the wall with this code, I've just about had it. This error is as indescriptive as can be.

My User entity:

https://pastebin.com/fqRJmMCc

```
package cc.serviceops.account;
import cc.serviceops.account.helpers.UserRole;
import cc.serviceops.organisation.Organisation;
import cc.serviceops.organisation.Team;
import cc.serviceops.ticket.Ticket;
import cc.serviceops.ticket.TicketAction;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.List;

@Entity @Table(name = "account")
@Getter @Setter
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String password;
    private String email;

    @Column(name ="first_name", nullable = true)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name ="last_name", nullable = true)
    private String lastName;

    @Nullable
    private String telephone;

    private boolean enabled = true;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole role = UserRole.GUEST;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true) @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true) @JoinColumn(name = "organisation_id")
    private Organisation organisation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Ticket> ticketList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "creator")
    private List<Ticket> createdTicketList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private  List<TicketAction> actionList;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return id == user.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

TicketController controller with just the function that holds user info:

https://pastebin.com/n7jeciAM

```
package cc.serviceops.ticket;
import cc.serviceops.Tools;
import cc.serviceops.account.User;
import cc.serviceops.account.dao.SignupService;
import cc.serviceops.account.dao.UserService;
import cc.serviceops.organisation.Organisation;
import cc.serviceops.organisation.dao.OrganisationService;
import cc.serviceops.organisation.Team;
import cc.serviceops.ticket.dao.TicketService;
import cc.serviceops.ticket.helpers.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Controller @AllArgsConstructor
public class TicketController {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final OrganisationService organisationService;
    private final TicketService ticketService;
    private final SignupService signupService;

    @GetMapping("/{organisation:^(?!css$|scripts$|img$|fonts$).*}/{ticket}")
    public String showTicket(@PathVariable("organisation") String organisationName,
                             @PathVariable("ticket") String ticketId,
                             Model model, Principal principal) {
...
        if (principal == null) {
            model.addAttribute("anonymousTicketDto", getAnonymousDtoFromTicket(ticket));
            return "ticket/anonymous";
        }

        model.addAttribute("ticketDto", getDtoFromTicket(ticket));
        return "ticket/ticket";
    }
...
    @PostMapping("/{organisation:^(?!css$|scripts$|img$|fonts$).*}/anonymous")
    public String doTicket(@Valid @ModelAttribute AnonymousTicketDto anonymousTicketDto, BindingResult bindingResult,
                           @PathVariable("organisation") String organisationName, Model model,
                           HttpServletRequest request) {
        Organisation activeOrganisation = organisationService.getOrganisationByName(organisationName);
        User activeUser = userService.getByEmail(anonymousTicketDto.getCreatorEmail());

        if (activeOrganisation == null) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Organisation cannot be found");
        }

        if (anonymousTicketDto.getCategory() == null || anonymousTicketDto.getCategory().getId() < 1) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("category.id", "ticket.category");
        }

        if (activeUser != null) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("creatorEmail", "user.email.duplicate");
        }

        if (!anonymousTicketDto.getPassword().equals(anonymousTicketDto.getPasswordConfirmation()) &&
                !anonymousTicketDto.getPasswordConfirmation().isBlank()) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("passwordConfirmation", "user.password.confirmation");
        }

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            fillTicketAttributes(activeOrganisation, model);
            model.addAttribute("anonymousTicketDto", anonymousTicketDto);
            return "ticket/anonymous";
        }

        activeUser = new User() {{
            setEmail(anonymousTicketDto.getCreatorEmail());
            setPassword(anonymousTicketDto.getPassword());
        }};

        activeUser = signupService.saveGuest(activeUser);
        // Password in activeUser is encrypted
        authWithHttpServletRequest(request, activeUser.getEmail(), anonymousTicketDto.getPassword());
        Ticket ticket = getTicketFromDto(anonymousTicketDto);
        ticket.setCreator(activeUser);
        ticket = ticketService.saveTicket(ticket);
        return String.format("redirect:/%s/%s?success", organisationName, ticket.getId());
    }
...
}
```

User service and repository essentials:

https://pastebin.com/acYUF7sN

```
package cc.serviceops.account.dao;
import cc.serviceops.account.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {}

=================
other file
=================
@Override
public User saveGuest(User user) {
    String password = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
    user.setPassword(password);
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Long story short is that the User object should only need a mail address, password and "enabled" field, which is by default true. Yet, for some reason when this bare minimum of info is passed to the database to make a user, I get an error saying TicketController is an "unknown entity". Even though TicketController shouldn't have anything to do with the database:

```
2021-09-17 21:08:28.134 ERROR 53256 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown entity: cc.serviceops.ticket.TicketController$2; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: cc.serviceops.ticket.TicketController$2] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: cc.serviceops.ticket.TicketController$2
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:723) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:597) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at cc.serviceops.account.dao.SignupServiceImpl.saveGuest(SignupServiceImpl.java:71) ~[classes/:na]
    at cc.serviceops.ticket.TicketController.doTicket(TicketController.java:279) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:133) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:132) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]

2021-09-17 21:08:28.140  WARN 53256 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

SignupServiceImpl:

```
pastebin.com/D1TmHUWp
```

@SpringBootApplication starter:

```
https://pastebin.com/bHFwMEnx
```

TicketController has a @Controller annotation, User has an @Entity, SignupServiceImpl has a @Service and still it complains about TicketController not being a known entity...

Config:
pom: `pastebin.com/B4EeKkmz`
application config: `pastebin.com/KuCndSVY`
db config class: `pastebin.com/FigJScit`
security config class: `pastebin.com/CuAxRErX`
web config class: `pastebin.com/qAHFY3jW`

Comment: Hi! Can you post your `persistence.xml` or any other configuration file/class you have?

Comment: Oh and please post all the error stacktrace not just a line.

Comment: Added the full stacktrace in OP.
pom: https://pastebin.com/B4EeKkmz
application config: https://pastebin.com/KuCndSVY
db config class: https://pastebin.com/FigJScit
security config class: https://pastebin.com/CuAxRErX
web config class: https://pastebin.com/qAHFY3jW

Should be about everything config-wise

Comment: Ok nice, post also `SignupServiceImpl` and your `persistence.xml`

Comment: Full SignupServiceImpl (had a tidbit "in other file" in the OP): https://pastebin.com/D1TmHUWp   
can't seem to find persistence.xml at first glance

Comment: Please not in links in  comments, put the as real code in your question.

Comment: And your `@SpringBootApplication` class please.

Comment: ok can I ask you a question? why you don't post your code instead of posting pastebin links? It is not helpful to navigate to dozens pastebin links to see information that should be existing in the question in the first place. StackOverflow has a special formating for code please use this and post your code there.

Comment: I've read a thread earlier saying that pastebin was preferred because full code would cause overhead. It's my first time posting since usually I can find this kind of stuff out pretty quickly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is that you are creating an anonymous class in your code.

```
 activeUser = new User() {{
        setEmail(anonymousTicketDto.getCreatorEmail());
        setPassword(anonymousTicketDto.getPassword());
    }};
```

needs to be something like

```
 activeUser = new User();
 activeUser.setEmail(anonymousTicketDto.getCreatorEmail());
 activeUser.setPassword(anonymousTicketDto.getPassword());
```

Some Background Information about anonymous classes in Java: https://www.baeldung.com/java-anonymous-classes

A cool tool that might ease the transformation between DTO and Entity in the Controller (I personally use it in some projects and really like it): https://mapstruct.org/

Comment: omg, I would've never guessed that this was the cause... and here I was, thinking I was saving myself some work typing less by omitting variable names.